# Linking Xerces in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am developing iPhone application that uses Xerxes to parse a file. I am trying to link the Xerxes library to my project but it is not working.

**I tried:**

- Downloading the binary distribution, and then adding the libxerces-c.a to "Link binary with library" in "Build Phases", and then I added the path to the include folder in "Header Search Path" under "Build Settings"
- Downloading the source code, compiling it using "make" from the command line, and then doing the steps above.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting linking errors such as:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "xercesc_3_1::DTDEntityDecl::serialize(xercesc_3_1::XSerializeEngine&)", referenced from:
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like the xerces library isn't built for the iPhone Simulator.  You'll have to customize the build process and do it yourself, creating a "fat binary" of i386, armv7, etc. architectures.

Comment: Can you help me please on how to build it for the iPhone Simulator?

Comment: There is no "off the shelf" answer to this problem.  Every project is different, but I would expect that someone has already solved this problem.  So searching is probably your best bet.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! I will search for it now

Comment: Could this be the problem? The [Xerces documentation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html) says you need to *compile your application with the XERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY preprocessor macro* when linking to the static Xerces-C++ library